# Authentication for a custom AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services

We’d like to build a custom AWS console for our company, geared to our company and needs - we already have the correct rules and permissions assigned to everyone, this is only a question of authentication. I’m not able to find a Login with AWS option - what’s the best way to use the existing login system and use those credentials With the JS SDK to make our own web console?

OAuth is the most common way to do this, but I can’t find it for AWS - GitHub, for instance has this https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/ which lets us build a custom Github dashboard.

Comment: You want users to be able to log in using the IAM User's username and password - the same way they currently access the AWS Console?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Most apps have an OAuth style system for this, can’t find one for AWS.

Comment: Did you find anything? I have a similar use case- would like something that is effectively a custom version of AWS console.  I could federate my custom web app to the same IDP that we use to log into AWS, but I was hoping for something lighter-weight like AWS Console itself acting as an OIDC provider.

Comment: Nothing yet. Maybe Cognito, but I haven't figured out if Cognito supports AWS itself as an auth method.